# How to access the updated state after setState method with react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, local-storage

On button click I want to set the state to **selectedMealPlan**, store the updated state to the **localStorage** and route to another component.

```
  const [selectedMealPlan, setSelectedMealPlan] = useContext(
    selectedMealPlanContext
  );
  const AddItem = (e: any) => {
    setSelectedMealPlan((prev: any) => ({
      ...prev,
      nutrients: {
        newValue: "newValue",
      },
    }));
    localStorage.setItem("mealplan", JSON.stringify(selectedMealPlan))
    history.push("/home");
  };
```

The problem is that setState() is asynchronous and I can only store the old state to localStorage, is there a way that I could access the most recent state?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `useEffect` to watch for changes to `selectedMealPlan`, and when detected, call `setItem`:

```
const AddItem = (e: any) => {
    setSelectedMealPlan((prev: any) => ({
        ...prev,
        nutrients: {
            newValue: "newValue",
        },
    }));
};
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("mealplan", JSON.stringify(selectedMealPlan))
    history.push("/home");
}, [selectedMealPlan]);
```

You could also save the new state object in a variable inside the `setSelectedMealPlan` callback, and both call `setItem` with it and return it for the new state, but that'd be impure and weird.

Comment: useEffect automatically redirects me to the home and I can't even call the AddItem function

Comment: What is `selectedMealPlan` originally? You could check that it's not the original object, and only carry out the effect body if it's different, so that the initial mount skips it.